# How to dynamically toggle the class to trigger different functons on-click

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyclassname

I'm trying to create some JavaScript code that listens for a click event on an element base on it's class name. This triggers a function that changes the class of the same element, allowing that elements click event to trigger a different function in order to achieve a toggle effect for a button.

However while the initial click event is successful and triggers the function, changing the class name of the element does not cause JavaScript to trigger the new function and instead it's sticking with the original function.

```
function tioDisable(e) {
var tioButton = document.getElementById(e.explicitOriginalTarget.name + '-tioButton');
tioButton.classList.remove('tio-enable');
tioButton.classList.add('tio-disable');
}

var tioDis = document.getElementsByClassName('tio-disable');
for (var i = 0; i < tioDis.length; i++) {
    tioDis[i].addEventListener('click',tioDisable);
}

function tioEnable(e) {
var tioButton = document.getElementById(e.explicitOriginalTarget.name + '-tioButton');

tioButton.classList.add('tio-enable');
tioButton.classList.remove('tio-disable');
}

var tioEn = document.getElementsByClassName('tio-enable');
for (var i = 0; i < tioEn.length; i++) {
    tioEn[i].addEventListener('click',tioEnable);
}

<img class="tio-enable" src="image.png" name="test" id="test-tioButton">`
```

I originally tried with querySelectorAll but I read in research that this created effectively a static list of elements, my research indicates that using getElementsByClassName should create a dynamic list however this is not working for me. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: You can provide your HTML to know more about what's the problem

Comment: The html for the image is there, is there something else you need?

Comment: so your goal is when you click enabled class image, you want to change it to disbaled class image and vice versa. is that correct?

Comment: Yes, click on the image, change it's class in order for the second click to trigger a different function

Answer (score 1):

When the code runs for the first time, it will add the `click` event based on the following codes. Because the initial code have the class `tio-enable`.

```
var tioEn = document.getElementsByClassName('tio-enable');
   for (var i = 0; i < tioEn.length; i++) {
      tioEn[i].addEventListener('click',tioEnable);
}
```

Now if you click the image, it will call the following function.

```
function tioEnable(e) {
   var tioButton = document.getElementById(e.explicitOriginalTarget.name + '-tioButton');

   tioButton.classList.add('tio-enable');
   tioButton.classList.remove('tio-disable');
}
```

In the above code, you are adding the classname `tio-enable`, which is already having and removing `tio-disable`. So nothing changed from your original content. So this will execute the same scenario again and again.

So what you have to do either change the `click` event listener to `tioDisable` or inside the `tioEnable` function you have to add the class `tio-Disable` and remove the class `tio-Enable`.

Will it work now? **NO.** Because after changing the classnames you didn't bind any event. Still it is binded with the old click listener. So you have to bind the `click` listener for the `tioDisable` classes and do the same for the other function also. Check the below snippet.

```js
function tioDisable(e) {
var tioButton = document.getElementById(e.target.name + '-tioButton');
console.log("called to Disable");
tioButton.classList.remove('tio-enable');
tioButton.classList.add('tio-disable');
var tioEn = document.getElementsByClassName('tio-enable');
for (var i = 0; i < tioEn.length; i++) {
    tioEn[i].addEventListener('click',tioEnable);
}
}
function tioEnable(e) {
var tioButton = document.getElementById(e.target.name + '-tioButton');
console.log("called to Enable");
tioButton.classList.add('tio-disable');
tioButton.classList.remove('tio-enable');
var tioDis = document.getElementsByClassName('tio-disable');
for (var i = 0; i < tioDis.length; i++) {
    tioDis[i].addEventListener('click',tioDisable);
}
}

var tioEn = document.getElementsByClassName('tio-enable');
for (var i = 0; i < tioEn.length; i++) {
    tioEn[i].addEventListener('click',tioEnable);
}
```

```css
.tio-enable {
  border:2px solid green;
  padding:10px;
}
.tio-disable {
  border:2px solid red;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<img class="tio-enable" src="image.png" name="test" id="test-tioButton">
```

May be there will be simple solution for this. But as per your code, I have given my solution.

Comment: Yes this works, Thanks! I had tried something similar when I was trying with querySelectorAll but not with getElementsByClassName.

Comment: Whilst this advice allowed the new class for the image to be registered with the event listener, it did not remove the old event lister, so both events were fired. I tried using `removeEventListener()`, but this failed to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this? I think this is what you need.

```
function tioToggle(e) {
    var tioButton = e.currentTarget;
    tioButton.classList.toggle('tio-enable');
    tioButton.classList.toggle('tio-disable');
}


var tioDis = document.getElementsByClassName('tio-disable');

for (var i = 0; i < tioDis.length; i++) {
    tioDis[i].addEventListener('click', tioToggle);
}

var tioEn = document.getElementsByClassName('tio-enable');

for (var i = 0; i < tioEn.length; i++) {
    tioEn[i].addEventListener('click', tioToggle);
}
```

[@Suresh Ponnukalai answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49422666/2928793) explains why your code was not working.